# await a new Promise in an async function

Tags: typescript, async-await

I have an async-based code base, and I need to interact with some "callback based" external libraries.
I though I could wrap the external library with a `Promise` that could act as a "bridge" and offer me an async facade.
I ended up with a doubt about how to define this wrapper.
In code:

```js
export function externalApi(onsuccess: (response: string) => void): void {
    // stuff
    onsuccess('response');
}

export async function myWrapper(): Promise<string> {
    return await new Promise((resolve) => externalApi(resolve));
}
```

My doubts are

- should `myWrapper` `await` the promise? or should it `return` it immediatly?
- if there is no `await`, should this function be marked as `async`?
- are there some penalties writing this `await new Promise(...)` stuff?

Comment: At first I thought this was a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises), but looking at the specific questions, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should `myWrapper` `await` the promise? or should it return it immediatly?

That's up to you. Doing `return await` at the top level of an `async` function isn't necessary,¹ but **might** make async stack traces clearer by including the `async` function in the async stack trace. So you might keep it for that reason, or you might remove it for that reason. :-) (I should note that with the latest V8, I can no longer see a difference in the stack traces, both include the wrapper function. So things may have moved on in that regard; I know async stack traces were a hot development area for a while.)

> if there is no `await`, should this function be marked as `async`?

No, **if** you remove the `await`, there's no reason for it to be `async`.

> are there some penalties writing this await new Promise(...) stuff?

If you mean specifically the `await` in the `return await`, then no, not when the promise you're using `await` on is a native promise. It used to introduce a (largely harmless) async tick into the settlement of the `async` function's promise, but the spec was updated to allow engines to avoid it.

---

¹ Using `return await` **not** at the top level of an `async` function **is** necessary if you want to catch the rejection of the promise in the function, or you want to do something in a `finally` clause, or something like that — anything where the `async` function's logic relies on that promise being settled before the `async` function itself returns. For instance, you'd need it here:

```
async function example() {
    try {
        return await somethingThatProvidesAPromise();
    } catch (e) {
        throw new WrapperError(e);
    }
}
```

and here

```
async function example() {
    const lock = acquireLock();
    try {
        return await doSomethingWith(lock);
    } finally {
        releaseLock(lock); // (Where `releaseLock` guarantees it nevers throws)
    }
}
```

Neither of those would be correct without the `await`.